# Is an estimator a function or a random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics

My questions:

Is an estimator both a function and a random variable?

Example:

when we say an estimator 
$$ T(X)$$
we mean :1. the rule,which is a function $T(X)$ 2.and the result $T=T(X)$,which is a random variable.

Comment: Yes, both. As an estimator, $T$ is a function of the possible observations, and if you apply it to a particular observation $x$ then it gives an estimate $T(x)$.  Since (before actually observing) the observation $X$ is a random variable, a function of it $T(X)$ is another random variable

Comment: An estimator is a statistic, which by definition is a function of sample observations (random variables) independent of the parameter of interest.

Comment: @Henry hi,henry.So, T is a function that can apply to a random variable X (before the observing) ,which will result in another random variable ,and also can apply to a observation x(after the observing),which will result in an estimate.Am i right?

Comment: That is how I understand it.  That is why people talk about things like the "variance of the maximum likelihood estimator/estimate"